# Bilinear image interpolation

Tags: python, performance, image, numpy, signal-processing

I have written a bilinear interpolant, which is working moderately well except that is painfuly slow. How can rewrite the code to make it faster? Using opencv directly isn't a valid answer.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.draw import line_aa
import cv2


def draw_line(img, x0, y0, x1, y1):
    r, c, w = line_aa(int(x0), int(y0), int(x1), int(y1))
    img[r, c] = w

def synth_img(sM, sN, pts_src):
    img = np.zeros((sM, sN))
    draw_line(img.T, pts_src[0][0], pts_src[0][1], pts_src[1][0], pts_src[1][1])
    draw_line(img.T, pts_src[1][0], pts_src[1][1], pts_src[2][0], pts_src[2][1])
    draw_line(img.T, pts_src[2][0], pts_src[2][1], pts_src[3][0], pts_src[3][1])
    draw_line(img.T, pts_src[3][0], pts_src[3][1], pts_src[0][0], pts_src[0][1])

    return img


sM, sN = 1440, 1450
pts_src = np.array([[ 520, 100],[ 1410, 220],[1240, 1310],[ 30, 1070]]).astype('float32')
img = synth_img(sN, sM, pts_src)

# Create a target image
M, N = 1050, 1480
img_dst = np.zeros((N, M))
pts_dst = np.array([[0, 0], [M-1, 0], [M-1, N-1], [0, N-1]], dtype='float32') 

X = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts_src, pts_dst)   # SRC to DST
X_inv = la.inv(X)                                   # DST to SRC

img_exp = cv2.warpPerspective(img, X, (M, N))

for y in np.arange(img_dst.shape[0]):
    for x in np.arange(img_dst.shape[1]):

        # Find the equivalent coordinates from DST space into SRC space
        Txy = X_inv  @ [x, y, 1]
        u, v, w = Txy / Txy[-1]

        # Find the neighboring points of v and u (src space)
        n = min(max(np.floor(v).astype('int'), 0), img.shape[0]-1)
        s = min(max(np.ceil(v).astype('int'),  0), img.shape[0]-1)
        w = min(max(np.floor(u).astype('int'), 0), img.shape[1]-1)
        e = min(max(np.ceil(u).astype('int'),  0), img.shape[1]-1)

        # Find the values in neighboring values of [u, v]
        q00 = img[n, w]
        q01 = img[n, e]
        q10 = img[s, w]
        q11 = img[s, e]

        x0, x1, y0, y1 = w, e, n, s

        A = np.array([
            [1, x0, y0, x0*y0],
            [1, x0, y1, x0*y1],
            [1, x1, y0, x1*y0],
            [1, x1, y1, x1*y1]
        ])

        b = np.array([[
            q00, q01, q10, q11
        ]]).T

        a = la.lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)[0].ravel()
        z = a[0] + a[1]*u + a[2]*v + a[3]*u*v
        img_dst[y, x] = z


plt.close()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(6,7), dpi=300, sharey=True, sharex=True)
ax[0][0].imshow(img, cmap='gray')
ax[0][0].set_title('Original')
ax[0][1].imshow(img_exp-img_dst, cmap='gray')
ax[0][1].set_title('Diff')
ax[1][0].imshow(img_dst, cmap='gray')
ax[1][0].set_title('Result')
ax[1][1].imshow(img_exp, cmap='gray')
ax[1][1].set_title('Expected')
#plt.show()
```

After some work I have got here, almost no for loops(except for a single list comprehension). I have added functions (as hinted on a comment MCVEs are not expected here, but I will leave there for history). This code has some helper functions and I really think that there is a lot of room for improvement, I just don't know how to do.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from itertools import product
from skimage.draw import line_aa



def draw_line(img, x0, y0, x1, y1):
    """Draw antaliased line from (x0,y0) to (x1, y1)"""
    r, c, w = line_aa(int(x0), int(y0), int(x1), int(y1))
    img[r, c] = w


def synth_img(sM, sN, pts_src):
    """Creates a simple synthetic image with a skewed rectangle"""
    img = np.zeros((sM, sN))
    draw_line(img.T, pts_src[0][0], pts_src[0][1], pts_src[1][0], pts_src[1][1])
    draw_line(img.T, pts_src[1][0], pts_src[1][1], pts_src[2][0], pts_src[2][1])
    draw_line(img.T, pts_src[2][0], pts_src[2][1], pts_src[3][0], pts_src[3][1])
    draw_line(img.T, pts_src[3][0], pts_src[3][1], pts_src[0][0], pts_src[0][1])

    return img


def extend_col(array):
    """Extend `array` adding a last columns of ones"""
    return np.hstack((array, np.ones((array.shape[0], 1))))


def reduce_row(array):
    """Reduce row space of array, dividing the whole array by the last
    column and returning the last first two columns"""
    return (array / array[-1])[:-1].T


def bilinear_interp(x, y, x0, x1, y0, y1, q00, q01, q10, q11):
    """Do bilinear interpolation given a point, a box and 
    values on box vetices"""
    q = np.array([[q00, q01],
                  [q10, q11]])
    xx = np.array([(x1 - x), (x - x0)])
    yy = np.array([(y1 - y), (y - y0)])
    # ATTENTION:
    # THIS IS DAMN UGLY. How to remove this comprehension and
    # transform this to a matrix/tensor multiplication?
    zz = np.array( [ a @ b @ c for a, b, c in zip(xx.T, q.T, yy.T)])
    return zz


def neigh_points(points):
    """Return the neighbor points of given uv"""
    return np.floor(points[0]), np.ceil(points[0]), np.floor(points[1]), np.ceil(points[1])


def clip(points, lower_u, upper_u, lower_v, upper_v):
    """Clip values in array given upper and lower limits"""
    u = points[:,:2]
    v = points[:,2:]
    u[u < lower_u] = lower_u
    u[u > upper_u] = upper_u
    v[v < lower_v] = lower_v
    v[v > upper_v] = upper_v


def interpolate(M, image):
    """Executes the interpolation on image based on M transform matrix"""
    MT = M.T
    u, v = MT[0], MT[1]
    w, e = MT[2].astype('int'), MT[3].astype('int')
    n, s = MT[4].astype('int'), MT[5].astype('int')
    q00 = image[n, w]
    q01 = image[n, e]
    q10 = image[s, w]
    q11 = image[s, e]
    return bilinear_interp(u, v, w, e, n, s, q00, q01, q10, q11)


def image_warp(M, img, shape):
    """Look ma! No for's

    Probably a lot to improve.
    """
    rxc = product(range(shape[0]), range(shape[1]))
    uv = reduce_row(la.inv(M) @ extend_col(np.array(list(rxc))).T)
    uv_neigh = np.array(neigh_points(uv.T)).T
    lower_u, upper_u, lower_v, upper_v = 0, img.shape[1]-1, 0, img.shape[0]-1
    clip(uv_neigh, lower_u, upper_u, lower_v, upper_v)
    coords = np.hstack((uv, uv_neigh))
    # ATTENTION:
    # This transformation should not need the rotation, something
    # is wrong here in `interpolate`
    return np.flip(np.rot90(interpolate(coords, img).reshape(shape),3), 1).astype('uint8')


def main():
    sM, sN = 1440, 1450
    pts_src = np.array([[ 526., 107],[ 1413, 227],[1245, 1313],[ 30, 1076]], dtype='float32')
    img = synth_img(sN, sM, pts_src)

    # Create a target image (100 dpi A4 sheet)
    N, M = 1480, 1050
    pts_dst = np.array([[0., 0], [M-1, 0], [M-1, N-1], [0, N-1]], dtype='float32')

    # Get transformation matrix from SRC to DST
    X = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts_src, pts_dst)
    img_dst =  image_warp(X, img, (M, N))
    img_exp = cv2.warpPerspective(img, X, (M, N))

    plt.close()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(6,7), dpi=300)
    ax[0][0].imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    ax[0][0].set_title('Original')
    ax[0][1].imshow(np.abs(img_exp-img_dst), cmap='gray')
    ax[0][1].set_title('Diff')
    ax[1][0].imshow(img_dst, cmap='gray')
    ax[1][0].set_title('Result')
    ax[1][1].imshow(img_exp, cmap='gray')
    ax[1][1].set_title('Expected')
    plt.show()
```

Actually, my `image_warp` function mimics `cv2.warpPerspective`. Almost got there except for two things:

1. First pixel `[0][0]` is weirdly set as 0. But looking the return from `zz` in `bilinear_interp` function the value is correct.
2. Some rounding issues in values (when comparing to OpenCV's result). Tried to use `np.ceil`, `np.floor`, `np.round` and plain `astype('uint8')`, but none returned perfect results matching OpenCVs. Left as is using the option that gives the smallest error (using opencv's output as reference).

About the code, I have some special concerns. There are some very ugly parts. I can point some:

1. In `bilinear_inter` the calculation of `zz` is a VERY UGLY and slow list comprehension. Converting types there and back again.
2. In `image_warp` there is an excessive number of conversion to list and numpy arrays and transposes.
3. In `image_warp` I'm rotating and flipping the results. Don't know what is happening and where the error may be, since the vector space transfomation should result in the correct orientation.
4. I could use `np.clip` instead my own `clip`. But I treat the first two columns differently than the last two columns. Can `np.clip` do that somehow?
5. The `extend_col`/`reduce_row` trick works fine and is reasonably fast, but *ugly*. Any better approaches?

Of course any other improvements are very welcome.

Comment: Is this your real project code?  I would have expected a function (perhaps with a sample "main" program to drive it with synthetic input).  What we have here is more like the MCVE I'd expect on a [so] question.

Comment: yes. Indeed a MCVE. I have changed all function calls to *inlines* inside the for-loop.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is using opencv directly not a valid answer? Asking because when performance issues crop up in a language not primarily built for raw speed, seems like the usual thing to do would be delegate that stuff to a native library. Python isn't my go-to language, but if I were writing this for Lua(JIT), and found it to be unacceptably slow, I'd probably either whip something up in C or load up a suitable library (with the FFI, either way).

Comment: You're expected to show actual code from your project - not an MCVE.  Changing the structure so that we're reviewing something different is off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: Are you using a least squares fit to do linear interpolation? Yes, that will be slow... Linear interpolation is a weighted addition of the four (in 2D) values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to share some observations about your main concerns given at the end of the question. Let's start from the back:

### 5. `extend_col`/`reduce_row`

From what I can see, the "trick" here is to bring the points into a [homogenous coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) and back. Therefore, I would propose to change the name of both functions to `to_homogeneous` and `from_homogeneous` or something similar. I also would propose a more straightforward implementation of `from_homogeneous`:

```
def to_homogeneous(array):
    """Extend `array` adding a last columns of ones"""
    # alternatively:
    # rows, cols = array.shape
    # arr = np.empty((rows, cols+1))
    # arr[:, :-1] = array
    # arr[:, -1] = 1
    # or:
    # arr = np.ones((rows, cols+1))
    # arr[:, :-1] = array
    return np.hstack((array, np.ones((array.shape[0], 1))))


def from_homogeneous(array):
    """Divide the array by the last column and return all but the last one"""
    return array[:, :-1] / array[:, -1, np.newaxis]
```

Since \$(A\cdot B)^T=B^T\cdot A^T\$ you can get rid of some of the transpositions in `image_warp`:

```
rxc = np.array(list(product(range(shape[0]), range(shape[1]))))
uv = from_homogeneous(to_homogeneous(rxc) @ la.inv(M).T)
```

I'm also relatively sure that there has to be a better way other than `itertools.product` here, but I haven't found it yet ;-)

### 4. `clip` vs. `np.clip`

As you rightfully suspected, you could use `np.clip` for the task directly. If you look at its [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html), you'll see, that you can pass array-like arguments as upper and lower bounds.

```
uv_neigh = np.clip(
    uv_neigh,
    [lower_u, lower_u, lower_v, lower_v],
    [upper_u, upper_u, upper_v, upper_v]
)
```

Please verify this yourself, for what I've seen it always delivers the same results as your original implementation.

### 3. Rotating and flipping the results in `image_warp`

Maybe later.

### 2. Reducing conversions and transpositions

While talking about the 5th point, I already presented a first step towards reducing the amount of transpositions. The part where `uv_neigh` is computed is another candidate to cut some transpositions. Rewriting it to make use of the full power of numpy will help as a first step:

```
def neighboring_points(points):
    """Return the neighbor points of given uv"""
    neigh_np = np.empty((points.shape[0], 4))
    neigh_np[:, 0::2] = np.floor(points)
    neigh_np[:, 1::2] = np.ceil(points)
    return neigh_np
```

This implementation creates a numpy array of the right size and then fills its 1st and 3rd column with the floored coordinates  and the 2nd and 4th column with the ceiled coordinates of the points. Again, this should be fully compatible with your original implementation, but without all the transpositions and converting back and forth between Python and numpy.

With this change also in place, `image_warp` now looks much friendlier:

```
def image_warp(M, img, shape):
    rxc = np.array(list(product(range(shape[0]), range(shape[1]))))
    uv = from_homogeneous(to_homogeneous(rxc) @ la.inv(M).T)

    uv_neigh = neighboring_points(uv)

    # you could also move this into a function as before
    lower_u, upper_u, lower_v, upper_v = 0, img.shape[1]-1, 0, img.shape[0]-1
    uv_neigh = np.clip(
        uv_neigh,
        [lower_u, lower_u, lower_v, lower_v],
        [upper_u, upper_u, upper_v, upper_v]
    )
    coords = np.hstack((uv, uv_neigh))

    return np.flip(np.rot90(interpolate(coords, img).reshape(shape), 3), 1).astype('uint8')
```

### 1. List comprehension in `bilinear_interp`

Indeed, the list comprehension here seems to be the biggest bottleneck of the code. Since I wasn't fully able to decipher all the cryptic variable names in your code and not had so much time at hand to really wrap my head around the problem, I took the lazy approach and threw the just-in-time compiler [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) (i.e. it compiles plain Python/numpy code to a faster platform-specific code) at the problem to see how it went. This is the code I ended up with:

```
from numba import jit


@jit(nopython=True)
def _bilinear_core(xx, q, yy):
    n = xx.shape[1]
    zz = np.empty((n, ))
    xx = xx.T
    q = q.T
    yy = yy.T
    for i in range(n):
        zz[i] = xx[i, :] @ q[i, :] @ yy[i, :].T
    return zz


def bilinear_interp(x, y, x0, x1, y0, y1, q00, q01, q10, q11):
    """Do bilinear interpolation given a point, a box and
    values on box vetices"""
    q = np.array([[q00, q01], [q10, q11]])
    xx = np.array([(x1 - x), (x - x0)])
    yy = np.array([(y1 - y), (y - y0)])
    return _bilinear_core(xx, q, yy)
```

As you can see, I had to make some changes to use numba's faster [nopython mode](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#nopython). The biggest change is that you cannot use `zip(...)` in that mode, as well as some other convenient functions available in Python. Splitting the code up in two functions was likely not necessary, but I like to do it nevertheless to keep numba-specific modifications contained to a small scope. Other than this, the code is almost unchanged and it's still written in pure Python/numpy.

But what are the benefits of these extra hoops you now have to jump through? Ignoring all the plotting and OpenCV's reference implementation, your `main` function runs in about \$10s\$ on my old laptop. Using numba and all the changes presented here in this answer to this point, the same main function now runs in \$3.2s\$*. Not bad, isn't it?

---

* When timing functions that (try to) use numba JIT, you have to take care to run the code at least twice and ignore the first measurement, since the first measurement would otherwise include the time numba needs to compile the function. In this example here, the first run takes about \$4.3s\$, which means that round about \$1.1s\$ are spent on the compilation process.